# Using DomDocument with SilverStripe

Tags: php, domdocument, silverstripe

I'm using SilverStripe 2.4.7 and DomDocument.  I have put together the following code which works as expected when used within a standalone PHP file.  **Please note the URL is not the actual URL I am calling but I can't post it publically**

```
$url = "http://www.somesite.com/";

  $dom = new DOMDocument(); 
  $dom->validate(); **I took this line out to fix the first error** 
  $dom->loadHTMLFile($url);

  foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $item) { 
     $value = $item->getAttribute('src'); 
   $item->setAttribute('src', 'http://www.somesite.com/' . $value); 
  }

  foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('script') as $item) { 
     $value2 = $item->getAttribute('src'); 
   $item->setAttribute('src', 'http://www.somesite.com/' . $value2); 
  }

  foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $item) { 
     $value4 = $item->getAttribute('href'); 
   $item->setAttribute('href', 'http://www.somesite.com/' . $value4); 
  } 

  $s = $dom->getElementById('searchbox_button'); 
  $value5 = $s->getAttribute('src'); 
$s->setAttribute('src', 'http://www.somesite.com/' . $value5);

$cr = $dom->getElementById('content_right'); 
$cl = $dom->getElementById('content_left'); 
  $fb = $dom->getElementById('siteclock'); 
  $fb->parentNode->removeChild($fb);

  $content = $dom->getElementById('content'); 
  $dom->appendChild($content); 
  $content->removeChild($cr); 
  $content->removeChild($cl);

  foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('link') as $item) { 
     $value3 = $item->getAttribute('href'); 
   $item->setAttribute('href', 'http://www.somesite.com/' . $value3); 
  }

  $offers = DataObject::get('AdminOffer');

  $div = $dom->createElement('div'); 
  $div->setAttribute("class", "offerBox"); 
  $div->setAttribute("style", "width: 33.33333%; overflow: hidden; border: 2px solid #80bd01");

  $content->appendChild($div);

  $img = $dom->createElement('img'); 
  $img->setAttribute("src", "http://www.somesite.com/$offers->Photo"); 
  $img->setAttribute("alt", "$offers->Title"); 
  $img->setAttribute("width", "120px"); 
  $img->setAttribute("style", "float: left; margin: 5px;");

  $div->appendChild($img);

  $p = $dom->createElement('p'); 
  $p->setAttribute("style", "float: left; word-wrap:normal; width: auto"); 
  $div->appendChild($p);

  $bTitle = $dom->createElement('b', "Offers->Title");

  $p->appendChild($bTitle);

  $break1 = $dom->createElement('br/'); 
  $p->appendChild($break1);

  $bPrice = $dom->createElement('b', "Offers->Price");

  $p->appendChild($bPrice); 
  $break2 = $dom->createElement('br/'); 
  $p->appendChild($break2);

  $bExpires = $dom->createElement('b', "Offers->Expires");

  $p->appendChild($bExpires);

  $dom->formatOutput = true;

  return $dom->saveHTML();
```

However, when I add it to my page controller it tells me `No DTD given in XML-Document`.

I have tried adding a DTD in the following way but get a server error when I do.

```
    $dom = DOMImplementation::createDocumentType('html',
             '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN',
             'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd');
```

I am guessing that SilverStripe specifies an XML DTD and this causes an error with the HTML being received when I call the validate method.  However when I comment out the validate call I get an error that a namespace is not defined in the HTML being received. I found an older post specifying that SilverStripe templates use an XML DTD so I'm wondering how I can override this?

I'd appreciate any advice and if I haven't been clear about something please let me know and I will edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with SilverStripe's error reporting.  Since I was using it in dev mode it was throwing errors that didn't actually matter.  Since I need to continue working in dev mode for the time being I had to include `@` to suppress errors on the lines that were causing the problems.

**Example**

```
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
```

I also had to remove the validate line which I have since learned was in completely the wrong place anyway.

I hope this helps someone.